# Sentiment analysis using Text Analytics API and Postman

Tags: postman, sentiment-analysis, azure-cognitive-services, text-analytics-api

I have a dataset of 600000 Tweets and want to do Sentiment Analysis using Microsoft Azure Cognitive services. I have a key and endpoint and limitation of 5000 requests and 1000 records in each request. I have tested 4 different ways:

1- PowerBI: problem is that in each request it sends just 1 record. So my limitation will be over after just 5000 records.

2- "mscstexta4r" library in R: Problem is that it gives 404 error. I couldn't get around the error.

3-https://northeurope.dev.cognitive.microsoft.com/docs/services/TextAnalytics.V2.0/operations/56f30ceeeda5650db055a3c9/console

With my credentials, it works. Just the problem is that I can't iterate through 600000 records, 1000 record per time.

4- Postman. It works with postman as well, but the same problem which I don't know how to iterate through 600000 records, 1000 record per time.

Can you tell me how to iterate through my records using postman? Or is there a simpler way to do this?

a sample of request body is:

```
{"documents": 
   [{"id":20001,"text":"hey volkswagen fans next my ride my story for will be 
   this vw microbus from framingham htt","language":"en"}, 
   {"id":20002,"text":"volkswagen just re released everyone favourite hippy 
   van now it electric","language":"en"},{"id":20003,"text":"volkswagen ceo 
   we will have transformed all of our new cars into smaphones on wheels 
   connectedcar","language":"en"}]
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I did it using Python. Check https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cognitive-services/text-analytics/quickstarts/python for the guidline.